# CMTTransactionfactory replacement in Hibernate 5.4 .Trying to get new transaction with JTAplatform resolver but getting no transaction in progress

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, ejb

HI We are migrating hibernate 3 to 5.4.25 >Please help me to get CMT transactionfactory replacement in hibernate 5 as it is deprecated and i am getting no transaction is in progress if i use session.flush() in my DAO class GET methos. Kindly help

Comment: I have done the similar migration recently, if you are using Hibernate in combination with Spring then I can share my approach

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from [link](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2015-November/013625.html)

> Its not just org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory that was
> removed; all of the TransactionFactory classes were removed.  Actually I
> think we should add them as resolvable names:
>
> - org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory
>   ->
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl
> - org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
>   -> org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl
> - org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory ->
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl

Actually, I have recently done a similar migration where I have completely changed the transaction-related blocks to  Spring's imperative transaction infrastructure.
I have used `PlatformTransactionManager` which is the default implementations of this strategy interface are `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager and org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager`, which can serve as an implementation guide for other transaction strategies.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class DbConfig{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager(LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(lsfb.getObject());
      }
      
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        
        lsfb.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
            
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", <hibernateDialect>);
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.isolation",2);  // READ_COMMITTED
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql); //To show sql or not
        //...configurable hibernate properties to add 
        
        lsfb.setHibernateProperties(properties);
        lsfb.setPackagesToScan("com.demo.entity.model"");
        return lsfb;
    }

}
```

JavaDoc about the `PlatformTransactionManager`([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/HibernateTransactionManager.html))

> PlatformTransactionManager implementation for a single Hibernate
> SessionFactory. Binds a Hibernate Session from the specified factory
> to the thread, potentially allowing for one thread-bound Session per
> factory. SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() is required for Hibernate
> access code that needs to support this transaction handling mechanism,
> with the SessionFactory being configured with SpringSessionContext.
> Supports custom isolation levels, and timeouts that get applied as
> Hibernate transaction timeouts.
>
> This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a
> single Hibernate SessionFactory for transactional data access, but it
> also supports direct DataSource access within a transaction (i.e.
> plain JDBC code working with the same DataSource). This allows for
> mixing services which access Hibernate and services which use plain
> JDBC (without being aware of Hibernate)! Application code needs to
> stick to the same simple Connection lookup pattern as with
> DataSourceTransactionManager (i.e.
> DataSourceUtils.getConnection(javax.sql.DataSource) or going through a
> TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy).

Comment: I added platform resolver, platform as jta and transaction coordinator class as JTA now , still it says no transaction in progress. I am working on cfg file configuration  , please guide me if i am wrong somewhere or I am not getting correct session from it . I added 3 properties:

Comment: I have the exact above working setup for my multiple Mysql-based applications in production, are you using XML-based spring configuration?

Comment: I added platform resolver, platform as jta and transaction coordinator class as JTA now ,  itsays no transaction in progress. I am working on cfg file configuration  , please guide me if i am wrong somewhere or I am not getting correct session from it . I added 3 properties: 1> hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class as jta org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform as platform and 3> org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformResolver as platform resolver. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#transactions

Comment: it will be good to analyse if you share the config file

Comment: <property name ="hibernate.transaction.coordinator.class">jta</property><propertyname="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform</property><property name ="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform_resolver">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformResolver</property>

Comment: earler it was <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property><property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup"/>

Comment: So Your application is booting correctly, but when there is a call to any transaction annotated method it is giving errors like no transaction is in progress, right?